# What does "find ... {} + || true" do?

Tags: bash

I'm working on the deployment script for a web application. The original author of the script wrote the following which I don't quite understand.

```
find */target -name myapp*.jar -exec mv -t $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS {} + || true
```

Googling around has got me so far, but I'm still a little unsure with what

```
{} + || true
```

is used for.

Comment: Explaining bash commands in English is what http://explainshell.com/ is for.

Comment: BTW, it's buggy as currently written. Make it `-name 'myapp*.jar'` -- with the quotes -- or it won't work right if there are files in the current working directory matching that pattern when it's run.

Comment: Also, you need quotes around the `$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS` expansion, or you'll have bugs if it contains whitespace or similar. That is: `mv -t "$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS"`.

Comment: Also, don't use all-caps names for your own local variables. See the relevant standards document laying out best practice in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph (relevant to shell variables because they share a namespace, overwriting environment variables when names overlap).

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this is a bit overbroad right now. For either "what does find ... -exec {} + do?" or "what does || true do?" we'd have a duplicate, but the chances of there being any other question that incorporates both those inner questions is low... which is pretty much exactly why we *have* rules about asking multiple unrelated questions as independent questions rather than combining them; without such enforcement, the knowledge base risks getting flooded with combinations of preexisting questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that link is friggin' amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{} +` suffix is part of the `-exec` action of `find`: It substitutes as many arguments as possible (that is, as many files found) on each `mv` invocation. (There's a limit to "as many as possible" because there's only so much space available in the region the operating system uses to store environment variables and command-line arguments, so if `find` has many results, multiple `mv` invocations can be needed even with `-exec ... {} +`).

---

Compare to this traditional command:

```
find */target -name 'myapp*.jar' -exec mv -t "$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS" {} ';'
```

This runs `mv` once per file found. Since `/bin/mv` is an external executable, this is implicitly expensive.

By contrast,

```
find */target -name 'myapp*.jar' -exec mv -t "$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS" {} +
```

...runs as few `mv` invocations as possible. (Note that this usage requires the `-t` extension, which is not specified by POSIX; thus, it's only available on GNU platforms).

---

Finally, `|| true` is simply a boolean OR operation: If the `find` fails, then `true` runs, forcing the command to always result in a truthful result. If you're running with `set -e`, this prevents the script from being exited in the event of a failure.

This can also be more tersely written as `||:`, as `:` is a synonym for `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` is replaced the filename found by the `find` command.

So it finds files with the `find` command, and executes `mv` for as many files as possible (this is marked by the `+`).

The `|| true` is a logical OR to the rest of the command, which basically makes sure the command has a zero exit status (which might be important for the rest of the script